# Ruby: Forwarding variable number of parameters including optional block to a different function

Tags: ruby, optional-parameters

I'm using a library function, which can be called in various ways - with a variable number of parameters, a block, or both, i.e. all of the following calls are valid:

```
libfunc
libfunc(1,2,3)
libfunc { 1 }
libfunc(1,2,3,4,5) { 6 }
```

Now I would write a function, which accepts the identical parameters as libfunc, invokes libfunc with these parameters (including the block), but does some preprocessing and postprocessing around this.

I ended up with this code:

```
def mylibfunc(*args)
  # .... do preprocessing
  if block_given?
    libfunc(*args) {yield}
  else
    libfunc(*args)
  end
  # .... do postprocessing
end
```

I find this design ugly. Isn't there a way to write this in a more concise way, avoiding the block_given? query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can indicate a [block argument](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html#label-Block+Argument) by `&` and pass it to the other method:

```
def mylibfunc(*args, &block)
  libfunc(*args, &block)
end
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought this forwarding would not work, if no block is passed to mylibfunc, but of course it has to! Silly me!